# Finding The Resultant Vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, vectors

A plane is flying southeast at 215 km/h. Suddenly there is a wind from the north at 75 km/h. What is the plane's new velocity with respect to the ground in standard position?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. Our [FAQ is very clear on *"Do my homework"-type physics questions*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add the vectors. Add component-wise in the north-south and west-east directions. Be careful for minus-signs. The velocity with respect to the ground will be the magnitude of the resulting vector.